# Undoing Common.js in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

### How to undo script / delete script / reset common.js

the script block me to edit

```
var elem = document.getElementById("content");
elem.innerHTML='newContent';
```

Resulting a whole page to newContent, it was an accident..

Comment: Can't you just roll back the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in such cases the simplest solution is (in Chromium) to

- click the icon next to the URL in the location bar,
- do JavaScript > block on this site,
- reload the page.

Then edit the MediaWiki pages in question and restore normal settings for your browser.

Similarly, in Firefox you can go to the general settings and disable CSS and/or JavaScript globally. This is a very useful trick to keep in mind for simple but hideous "attacks" via JS/CSS, intentional or unintentional.